# Add new line to text in UI of shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

is there a way to add a new line when putting text through the UI?

I currently have something like

```
mainPanel(
h3("This is my app!\n\n"),
h4("Download your data using the choose file button\n\n"),
h4("Thank you for using the app!")
)
```

but the new lines don't seem to be working.

Comment: you could try `br()`

Answer (score 9):

`\n` doesn't work in shiny app.
For the new line, you could use HTML tag `<br/>`:

```
  mainPanel(
    HTML(
     paste(
      h3("This is my app!"),'<br/>',
      h4("Download your data using the choose file button"),'<br/>',
      h4("Thank you for using the app!")
     )
    )
  )
```